# Entity Framework 5.0 db.savechange not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When I try to update my entry in update function it's execute successfully but database not updated.

Please find the following code

```
public static string UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    using (var db = new RandDEntities())
    {
         var empObj = db.Employees.First(x => x.EmpID == employee.EmpID);
         db.Entry(empObj).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: try to trace sql statement, are you reach the db?

Comment: sql profiler not in my system

Comment: How do you know it's not working? It looks to me like you are just loading empObj by EmpID, not changing anything, and then saving it. There are no properties changed, so nothing to save.

Comment: Thank you, now i chanage my code like  db.Entry(empObj).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);  but this code not support to concurrency. how to apply concurrency in my update entity

Comment: i have check lot of bolgs but it's not supported to me. and my porject in 3 tire architecture please help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're saving the wrong entity (i.e. `empObj`) instead of the entity that has the changes (i.e. `employee`).  Your code pulls `empObj` out of the database, and then turns around and saves it, without making any changes to it.  You need to modify your code as follows:

```cs
public static string UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    using (var db = new RandDEntities())
    {
         db.Employees.Attach(employee);
         db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That has absolutely nothing to do with Entity Framework but more with the fact that you likely use localdb and your database is not where you think it is, and reinitialized (reset) to empty every time you press start.

This question, in dozens of variants, gets asked over and overy by people not bothering to check where they look (and then realizing the database files have different paths).

Comment: I am new in this entity framwork please help to update in database

Comment: Again, NOTHING to do with Entity Framework. The database you run is copied from a template every time you start the program in the debugger. Try reading the answers - it really helps. And stop blaming totally unrelated technologies.